# Service or Broadcast?

Tags: android, service, location, broadcastreceiver

**Scenario:**

The user can select a time interval (such as 5h). Every 15 minutes of that interval, I'll check the current location of user and take actions depending on the location.

**Question:**

So, which is best?

Will I need a `LocationListener` or `getLastKnowLocation()` based on some Criteria should resolve?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Implement `BroadcastReceiver` with `AlarmManager` that `setInexactRepeating`.After it handle your `getLastKnowLocation()` with Criteria and send broadcast wherever you want

Comment: Thanks =). I was thinking about doing that, I just wanted to be sure about this strategy. In 7 minutes I'll accept the answer.